# Determining $A,B,C$ in terms of $X,Y,Z$ given a linear equation for each

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of equations representing a linear transformation from the variables $A, B, C$ to $X, Y, Z$.  I know that this can be solved by substitution, but I can't figure out how to carry out that substitution.  How can this be done?  Here are my equations:

$A = \frac{1}{4}X + \frac{1}{2}Y + \frac{1}{4}Z$

$B = X - Y$

$C = Z - Y$

Now I want to retrieve the opposite transformation.  Given $A, B, C$, what are the values for $X, Y, Z$?  This can be solved by inverting a matrix about them, but I am hoping for a simple approach by substitution.

For full disclosure, this is exam review for me.  I know the question and answer, but how the substitution is carried out doesn't make sense to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second and third equation, you get $X = B + Y$ and $Z = C + Y$. Substitute in (four times) the first to get $4A = (B + Y) + 2Y + (C + Y) = B + C + 4Y$. So $Y = (4A - B - C)/4$ and so on ($X = (4A + 3B - C)/4$ and $Z = (4A - B + 3C)/4$).

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the following matrix equation $A=PX$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\\C \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac 1 4 & \frac 1 4  &\frac 1 4\\ 1&0&-1&\\0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{bmatrix}$$

Yo're looking for a $Q$ such that $X=QA$. Working from what you have, you must see that $Q=P^{-1}$.

Hope you can evaluate the inverse...

---

**Hint**

Invert the co-efficient matrix...

Comment: Sorry.  I pointed out in the question that I know this can be solved by inverting a matrix, but I'm looking for the substitution approach :)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not read the question properly. :-(